# Prepositional vs. locative case

Tags: грамматика, падежи, предлоги

We have, I think, five prepositions that take or may take the prepositional case: в, на,  о, при, по. But which of these (appart from  в and на) take the locative in -ý when that form exists? And which don't?

Answer (score 2):

*При* can also govern the locative form, especially in poetic language, though this usage is quite archaic.

> Верстах в двух от него, возле неглубокого яра, при шляху, Григорий спешил казаков, расположил в ярке.
>
> Ой, при лужку, при лужке…

Note the mix of the two cases in the song lyric above.

Also note that the form in *-у* is used both in locative and prepositional for some nouns (*мост, полк, бок* etc.)

Prepositional has quite a limited use with *по* and can be replaced with dative in most cases.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. So при generally takes the prepositional, while the locative is archaic. And o and по never take the locative. Correct?

Comment: _По_ barely ever takes the prepositonal either. Hemingway's "For Whom the Bell Tolls" is _По ком звонит колокол_, but the answer in plural second would rather be _по вам_, not _по вас_ in the modern language, though the latter is still acceptable. Otherwise you're correct.

Comment: В мосте нет пользы - prepositional, no у